# Shuffled binary numbers

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Here are 0 to 15 in binary:

```
0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

I have shuffled and concatenated them to obtain this string:

```
11001011011011111101110011001110111010111010001101
```

Can you recover the order of each binary number in this string? No computers are allowed.

**Bonus:** can you find multiple solutions?

HINT:

> It is possible to make a simple modification to a solution to create another solution.

Comment: This is trivial to brute force, should there be a [tag:no-computers] tag?

Comment: yes good point. I will add it.

Comment: Have you checked if it is possible to deduce the solution entirely through logic, or are you expecting people to use trial and error?

Comment: there may be some trial and error involved

Comment: Could there be multiple valid solutions to this puzzle?

Comment: Just realized that there can be multiple solutions...find them all!

Comment: How will we know we've found them all without computers?

Comment: There is one more solution that can be found by hand. After that I will accept computer solutions.

Comment: @someone It turns out the search space is pretty small, so enumerating the solutions by hand doesn't take too long.

Comment: is there a string that only has 1 solution?

Comment: I like @Magma 's question as an even better puzzle.

Comment: I made a new puzzle with strings that have a single unique solution. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/123082/shuffled-binary-numbers-version-2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a total of:

> Twelve solutions:
>
> ```
>  1100 101 10 110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101 10 110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 10 1101 101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1 101
>  1100 101 10 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1 101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101 10 110 1 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10 1101 101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1 101
>  1100 101 10 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1 101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 101 10 110 1 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

> Firstly, there's only one possible place to take 1010 and 1000:
>
> ```
>  1100101101101111110111001100111011 1010 1110 1000 1101
> ```

> Then there is only one block of four or more 1's which must contain the 1111.
>
>  We now need three consecutive 1's for each of 111 and 1110.
>  There are no remaining blocks of four or more 1's, so 111 must be followed by 0 (the only number that starts with "0").
>  And neither of them can use the "11100" section which would require another number starting with "0".
>
>  That gives us the following four possibilities:
>
> ```
>  110010110110 1111 110111001100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  110010110110 1111 110111001100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100101101101 1111 10111001100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100101101101 1111 10111001100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

> Now look for 1001. We can't have 1,1001 at the start of the string because that leaves another number starting with "0").
>  So there is only one option in each case:
>
> ```
>  110010110110 1111 11011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  110010110110 1111 11011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

> Now we have some isolated sections that cannot be split further (100, 11), identifying two more numbers.
>  And the 1100 can only be at the start:
>
> ```
>  1100 10110110 1111 11011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10110110 1111 11011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

> Now 1011 can only go in one place without leaving a leading "0":
>
> ```
>  1100 10110110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10110110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

> In two of the four cases, that also isolates the 1, which means the final section cannot be split and must be 1101.
>  In the other two cases, we have two other places for the 1101, expanding our possibilities to eight:
>
> ```
>  1100 10110110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10110110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 10 1101 101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10110 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10 1101 101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 10110 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 101101101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

> Finally we still need to fit 101 and 110 somewhere.
>  There are only one or two ways to do that in each case, leading to the following twelve solutions
>
> ```
>  1100 101 10 110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101 10 110 1111 1 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 10 1101 101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1 101
>  1100 101 10 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1 101 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 101 10 110 1 1111 1011 1001 100 111 0 11 1010 1110 1000 1101
>  1100 10 1101 101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1 101
>  1100 101 10 1101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 110 1
>  1100 10 110 1 101 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
>  1100 101 10 110 1 1111 1011 1001 100 1110 11 1010 111 0 1000 1101
> ```

Comment: Great solution, well done!

Comment: I didn't expect someone to find all solutions by hand. Impressive!

Answer (score 6):

Solution:

> 1100
> 101
> 10
> 110
> 1111
> 1
> 1011
> 1001
> 100
> 111
> 0
> 11
> 1010
> 1110
> 1000
> 1101

> Started with the first four and spotted the last four. Found the next four at the start until i discovered the 0. To this point i thought every number must start with a 1. So i found the solution with luck and the wrong assumption.

Comment: Yes that's correct! But now I realized that my question has multiple plausible solutions... can you find any other ones?

Comment: Also welcome to Puzzling! I hope you like it here :)

Comment: Note (for the bonus): 101 10 110 1111 1 can also be 10 110 1 101 1111

Comment: @Stiv Or more simply 1111 1 can be 1 1111. My computer says there are 12 solutions, half of which are formed by swapping 111 0 and 1110.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis #oopsoverthinkingagain :)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis yep that's what I got with my search.