# Shuffled binary numbers version 2

Tags: mathematics, no-computers

Here are 0 to 15 in binary:

```
0 1 10 11 100 101 110 111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

I have shuffled and concatenated them to obtain the following strings:

1. `01011111001011110010101110110011110110111101100011`
2. `11101011111011011011111011100101100011100101011001`
3. `11111011111010011010101111000100011101101010011111`

Can you recover the order of each binary number in each string? There is a single unique solution in each case. This fact should actually help you solve them. No computers are allowed.

Comment: Well, it is wery easy to publish such a kind of  puzzle. Hard to solve. But no problem for DNA solvers.

Comment: It was somewhat tricky to find strings that have a single solution.

Comment: About 0.8% of random shuffles produce a string with a single solution. One can easily generate thousands of these puzzles. Of course, building one manually is a puzzle in and of itself.

Comment: Perhaps this is the next Sudoku? You could also extend it to more numbers. I found a string with numbers 0 to 31 with a single solution.

Comment: Curious which string has the *highest* number of possible shuffles *S_max*, and what that number is? and can we get a closed-form expression for *S_max* as a function of the number of binary digits b (in this case b=4)?

Comment: @smci At least 718, with 10011101100101010111111111110101011110110011101000 (hexadecimal: 0x27655ffd5ece8) I'll let the code run overnight to see what else pops up.

Comment: for b=3, S_max=20 with 100101111111010110.

Comment: Looks like it is important to have many consecutive 1 at some point, as there many ways to split them.

Comment: 786 with this string: 11011001110101010101111111111101011100111011001000

Comment: I expect this to be maximal: 0x22765d57ff6ce (890 solutions) 1000.10011101100.10111010101011111111111011011001110, also 0x2765d57ff6ce8 which has 1000 on the right instead of the left. The other four permutations of the three groups (0x22eabffb674ec, 0x2eabffb6744ec, 0x2eabffb674ec8, 0x27645d57ff6ce) have 886 solutions each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First string:

> First, there's only one `000`, which must be part of `1000`, and the initial `0` must stand alone: 
>  `0 1011111001011110010101110110011110110111101 1000 11`

Next, note that

> The three `00` pairs must lie in `100`, `1001`, and `1100`, in some order. The third of these is the only one that isn't within the sequence `0010`, so that must be where `1001` goes: 
>  `0 10111110010111100101011101 1001 1110110111101 1000 11`

Next, there's only one way

> To place the sequence `1111` without leaving a leading `0`, within the sequence `11111`. From there we can also place `100`, and thus `1100`: 
>  `0 10 1111 100 1011 1100 101011101 1001 1110110111101 1000 11`

By the same argument,

> We can also place the `111` within the only remaining `1111` sequence: 
>  `0 10 1111 100 1011 1100 101011101 1001 1110110 111 101 1000 11`

Now, we can finish things off:

> `0 10 1111 100 1011 1100 1010 1 1101 1001 1110 110 111 101 1000 11`

---

Second string:

> First, we can find the sequence `000` and thus the string `1000`: 
>  `11101011111011011011111011100101 1000 11100101011001`

Next, let's look at:

> The three occurrences of `00`. One of them must be within `1001`, which is probably the last occurrence. It's not guaranteed, but it allows us to not lock in the `0`. We can then put separators after the other two `00`s: 
>  `11101011111011011011111011100 101 1000 11100 10101 1001`

Next let's guess that

> The `10101` sequence near the end shookd be split into `1010` and `1`, as we already have a `101`: 
>  `11101011111011011011111011100 101 1000 11100 1010 1 1001`

We can now place

> The `100` and `1100`, so as not to duplicate the `1`: 
>  `1110101111101101101111101 1100 101 1000 11 100 1010 1 1001`

Now there's only one place for the

> `1111` to go, in the first `11111` block, as the second would create another `101`. Instead, let's carve a `1101` out of the second block: 
>  `111010 1111 10110110111 1101 1100 101 1000 11 100 1010 1 1001`

And now let's finish things up:

> `1110 10 1111 1011 0 110 111 1101 1100 101 1000 11 100 1010 1 1001`

---

Third string:

> Note that there's two `000` sequences, so one is in a `1000`, and the other is `...00 0`. So there's a break after each `000`: 
>  `11111011111010011010101111000 1000 11101101010011111`

Next, let's look at

> The two other `00` sequences. They both are within `0100` sequences, so neither is in the `1100`. So we can identify the `1100`: 
>  `111110111110100110101011 1100 0 1000 11101101010011111`

Next, we can

> Separate out the other two `00` sequences, at least their beginnings: 
>  `111110111110 100110101011 1100 0 1000 111011010 10011111`

Next, note that because there's a unique solution,

> The final `00` sequence can't be within a `100` sequence, because the five `11111` sequence could be divided multiple ways. Thus: 
>  `111110111110 100 110101011 1100 0 1000 111011010 1001 1111`

Next, note that

> The later big string can't be split as `1110 110 10`, because there's nothing left for the end of the first big string. Thus: 
>  `111110111110 100 110101011 1100 0 1000 11101 1010 1001 1111`

Now, let's start guessing to wrap it up:

> `111 1101 1 1110 100 110 10 1011 1100 0 1000 11 101 1010 1001 1111`

Comment: great deduction

Comment: Congratulations you have completed this difficult puzzle!